# DNSMasq Not Resolving Addresses on Mac Local Web Development Environment

Tags: macos, dns, apache2, localhost, virtualhost

I've setup my local web development environment according to -http://mallinson.ca/osx-web-development/. I have done this before, and I got on a new computer, and am trying to do it again. I'm running Apache 2.4.9 on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.2 and directing the DNS with dnsmasq.

When I try to go to home.dev, it received this error:

```
Error code: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

When I run scutil --dns, it seems to resolve it correctly as:

```
resolver #3
  domain   : dev
  nameserver[0] : 127.0.0.1
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : Reachable,Local Address
```

However, when I:

```
ping -c 1 home.dev
```

I get

```
ping: cannot resolve home.dev: Unknown host
```

Here is my reference to it in vhosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   VirtualDocumentRoot "/Volumes/Work/Home/www"
   ServerName home.dev
   UseCanonicalName Off
</Virtualhost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was a change from Maverick's to Yosemite. In Yosemite, I had to add "port 35353" to the /etc/resolver files as well as as the config file for DNSmasq. I know for a fact I didn't originally do that, and it originally worked, so there was a change somewhere in there that broke it. Possibly also from a newer version of DNSmasq.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, I had to add a 127.0.0.1 DNS entry in my Network Preferences.[image]